# RSpec - how to test a class including HTTParty

Tags: ruby, rspec, httparty

I have a code like this:

```
class FooBar
  include HTTParty

  def self.token
    fail Project::MissingToken unless Project::Config.key?("project_token")
    Project::Config.fetch("project_token")
  end

  base_uri "https://website.com/api"
  default_params token: token
end
```

Now I need to test a case when `Project::Config` doesn't contain the key and raises the exception. I was considering something like that:

```
context "token is not given" do
  subject { Project::FooBar }

  it "should raise an error" do
    expect(Project::Config).to receive(:key?).with("project_token").and_return(false)
    expect { subject }.to raise_error(Project::MissingToken)
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work properly. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Change your `subject` to the following:

```
subject { described_class.token }
```

Comment: Or forget about using `subject` and just inline it: `expect { Project::FooBar.token }.to raise_error(Project::MissingToken)`.

Comment: Yeah, what @AndyWaite said, but I would personally still use `described_class` instead of `Project::Foobar`.